# How to optimise google BigQuery with 17+ tables which contains approx. 55 GB of data?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata, analytics

I have a huge amount of data store which contains almost 20+ tables. all tables contain data in GB.

So basically I'm exporting all data into CSV for analysis. I have 17+ tables in join query which almost process billions of records. Google says it will process `10 GB` data.

Now the problem is query taking too much time & resources, sometimes query fails with resource limit. how can I optimize such a query?

FYI: I'm using `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Exporting 55 Gbytes of data for analysis seems like the root of the problem.  You should be able to summarize the data in BigQuery to reduce the data needed downstream.

Comment: I already have only needed columns in the select clause.

Comment: In this case, i think it's optimal to break down your logic and materialize some intermediate joins into intermediate tables.  BQ is best at working vertically (sum, count, aggregating) rather than horizontally (joins).  Reducing the # of joins in your queries is (or should be) a best practice in BQ.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to optimize your query is implement Partitioning & Clustering. Best solution is to implement [partitioning and Clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) on fields over which Joining conditions are done.